# Laravel environment variable in vue component

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, environment-variables, laravel-valet

I'm having a problem getting the correct value for an environment variable I have set. I am working on a localhost with valet. This specific domain is configure for ssl (`valet secure`), and the URL I am on also shows the certificate and correct URL.

I have the following in my .env file:

```
APP_URL=https://pad.eppo
MIX_APP_URL=${APP_URL}
```

I then call on this in my Vue component:

```
console.log("Environment URL: " + process.env.MIX_APP_URL);
```

Expected result:

```
https://pad.eppo
```

Result:

```
http://pad.eppo
```

There is no cache or cookies involved. Both have been cleared to double check. I have recompiled using `npm run watch`, since this is necessary when changing the variables. I am out of ideas as to why this problem exists. It is a big problem since my axios requests give errors on this.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Force HTTPS in your Laravel application:

```
URL::forceScheme('https');
```

Add this line at the begin of your `web.php` file. In that way `${APP_URL}` will be returned with HTTPS protocol.

**Also ensure your config is not cached - run:**

```
php artisan config:clear
```

Comment: Hello, unfortunately this doesn't work either.
Also when I view my env in the terminal, it shows the variable without https. It must be cached somewhere I believe, but where..

Comment: @nepp95 Did you cached your config? Run `php artisan config:clear`.